# How to launch a file using OpenFileDialog in WinForm/WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms

After the file has been selected from OpenFileDialog, I want file to be launched in the respective application - PDF in acrobat reader, word in winword and so forth.I am looking for built in functionality if it exists, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
 `Process.Start("file.pdf")`

Comment: I am familiar with that approach but I was expecting something in built within OpenFileDialog component. Thanks though !

Comment: If you´re using the default windows OpenFileDialog, you can right-click the file and choose the default explorer actions for this file type. Other than that, the OpenFileDialog just gives you the information about the selected file.

Comment: @Kumar: You can only get file streams from that dialog (using `OpenFile()` for example) like this, it's an OpenFileDialog after all, not a LaunchFileWithWhateverApplicationDialog...